# Mysql counting number of occurrences

Tags: mysql, database

So lets say we have the following table of data:

```
A   |   B
_________
1   |   2
3   |   4
5   |   6
6   |   5
```

And what if I wanted to count the times the same numbers collide or are in the same line?  So in the above example 1-2 and 3-4 would return a count of one because they are on the same line only once however 5-6 and 6-5 would return a value of 2.

A more real life illustration: think that the numbers are sport team id's and the A and B columns determine the host-team and the guest-team.  Ao teams 5 and 6 have played a total of 2 games against each other, first team 5 as a host and then team 6 as a host.

So how could I count these in mysql?

Comment: This could be easier to compute if the numbers were in a predictable order, like if A < B as a rule. Then you'd only be testing for 5-6 and not 6-5 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS fixtures;
CREATE TABLE fixtures
(fixture_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,home INT NOT NULL
,away INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO fixtures (home,away) VALUES (1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(6,5);

SELECT * FROM fixtures;
+------------+------+------+
| fixture_id | home | away |
+------------+------+------+
|          1 |    1 |    2 |
|          2 |    3 |    4 |
|          3 |    5 |    6 |
|          4 |    6 |    5 |
+------------+------+------+

SELECT LEAST(home,away) a,GREATEST(home,away) b, COUNT(*) ttl FROM fixtures GROUP BY a,b;
+---+---+-----+
| a | b | ttl |
+---+---+-----+
| 1 | 2 |   1 |
| 3 | 4 |   1 |
| 5 | 6 |   2 |
+---+---+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

As a-b is the same as b-a, you want to normalize that result:

```
SELECT LEAST(a,b) AS x, GREATEST(a,b) AS y ...
```

Now you can count the occurences:

```
SELECT LEAST(a,b) AS x, GREATEST(a,b) AS y, count(*) as c FROM tablename GROUP BY x,y
```

Greets

Comment: The MIN() and MAX() functions don't work this way neither in MySQL, nor in any RDBMS implementing ANSI-SQL Standard.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN A < B THEN A ELSE B END AS aa,
CASE WHEN B > A THEN B ELSE A END AS bb,
COUNT(*)
FROM
Table1 t1
GROUP BY aa, bb
```

See it live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd8e3/8/0).